# spark JDBC column size

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc

spark JDBC column size:

I"m trying to get column (VARCHAR) size, I'm using :

spark.read.jdbc(myDBconnectionSTring,scheam.table, connectionProperties)

to retrieve column name and type but I need for varchar column the size. 
In java JDBC Database Metadata I can get column name, type, and size.
Is it possible with spark?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apache Spark uses only a single uniform type for all text columns - `StringType` which is mapped to internal unsafe UTF representation. There is no difference in representation no matter the type used in the external storage.

Comment: Thx for the replay, I"m just looking for a way for retrieving  DB metadata, the same way Java does. (connection.getMetaData)